# Create new columns based on existing columns and values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

(1) Considering the following DataFrame:

```
    d   e     val
-----------------
1   0   40    125
2  10   35    150
3  11   30    110
4  15   65    115
```

Is there a way to get to the following row:

```
     val_0    val_10    val_11    val_15    e_0    e_10    e_11    e_15
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1      125      150        110       115     40      35      30      65
```

This is quite easily done with manually iterating over rows, but ideally I'd be looking for a vectorized solution. Basically, I think what I'm after is a way to create/assign rows based on some column name + a column value.

(2) Next step would be to actually output one row per value, given a group by column. To build on the example above, the following:

```
    d   e     val   gp
----------------------
1   0   40    125    3
2  10   35    150    3
3  11   30    110    3
4  15   65    115    3
1   0   70    225    4
2  10   85    250    4
3  11   90    210    4
4  15   95    215    4
```

Would output:

```
gp   val_0   val_10   val_11   val_15   e_0    e_10    e_11    e_15
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 3     125      150      110      115    40      35      30      65
 4     225      250      210      215    70      85      90      95
```

Again, doing (2) when having solved (1) can be done with a simple `groupby('gp').apply(some_fun)`, but if there existed a builtin way to do that in Pandas, that would be a massive benefit performance-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some dataframe reshaping and column heading flattening:

```
df_out = df.set_index('d').unstack().to_frame().T
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
```

Output:

```
   e_0  e_10  e_11  e_15  val_0  val_10  val_11  val_15
0   40    35    30    65    125     150     110     115
```

#### Edit to handle mutli rows

```
df_out = df.set_index(['gp','d']).unstack()
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
```

Output:

```
    e_0  e_10  e_11  e_15  val_0  val_10  val_11  val_15
gp                                                      
3    40    35    30    65    125     150     110     115
4    70    85    90    95    225     250     210     215

df_out = df_out.reset_index()

   gp  e_0  e_10  e_11  e_15  val_0  val_10  val_11  val_15
0   3   40    35    30    65    125     150     110     115
1   4   70    85    90    95    225     250     210     215
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution to the *original* question.

```
val = pd.Series(df['val'].values, index='val_'+df['d'].apply(str))
e = pd.Series(df['e'].values, index='e_'+df['e'].apply(str))

res = pd.concat([val, e]).to_frame().T

print(res)

   val_0  val_10  val_11  val_15  e_40  e_35  e_30  e_65
0    125     150     110     115    40    35    30    65
```

Comment: This is definitely interesting.